# Doesn't have access to assignment inside catch try

Tags: c#

The `celsius` and `temperature` in the `while` doesn't have access to the `celsius` and `temperature` in *try catch*. I have tried to make assignment outside of *try catch* but it doesn't help and doesn't comply.

```cs
using System;

namespace Hermods
{
    class Program
    {
        // method for converting Fahrenheit to Celsius with decimals
        public static double FahrToCels(int Fahr)
        {
            double cels = (Fahr - 32) * 5 / 9d;
            return cels;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi! Which tempreture would you like to have? Choose in Fahrenheit:");
            int temprature;
            double celsius;
            try
            {
                temprature = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                celsius = FahrToCels(temprature);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR! Enter only number!");
            }
            

            // asking user to optimize the tempreture between 73-77C
            while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77)
            {
                if (celsius < 73)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It is too cold. You have to pick a higher tempreture:");
                    celsius = FahrToCels(temprature);
                }
                else if (celsius > 77)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It is too hot! You have to pick a cooler tempreture:");
                    celsius = FahrToCels(temprature);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(celsius, 1));

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue:");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use them outside the try-catch because their value may never be assigned.

Just give an initial value:

```
public static double FahrToCels(int Fahr)
    {
        double cels = (Fahr - 32) * 5 / 9d;
        return cels;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi! Which tempreture would you like to have? Choose in Fahrenheit:");
        int temprature = 0;
        double celsius = 0;
        try
        {
            temprature = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            celsius = FahrToCels(temprature);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR! Enter only number!");
        }
        

        // asking user to optimize the tempreture between 73-77C
        while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77)
        {
            if (celsius < 73)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is too cold. You have to pick a higher tempreture:");
                celsius = FahrToCels(temprature);
            }
            else if (celsius > 77)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is too hot! You have to pick a cooler tempreture:");
                celsius = FahrToCels(temprature);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(celsius, 1));

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue:");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace your variable with this default values

```
int temprature = 0;
double celsius = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is any variable must be initialized before reading it!

```
int temprature;
double celsius;
try
{
    temprature = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    celsius = FahrToCels(temprature);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR! Enter only number!");
    // You catch the error and don't throw and exception, 
    // therefore it can happen that temprature and-or celsius is not initialized
}
```

Either initialize them before the try block

```
int temprature = 0;
double celsius = 0;
```

or throw an Exception from the catch block.